# Visualizing ANOVA Decomposition

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $f \in L^2[0,1]^d$ be a measurable function where $d \in \mathbb{N}$.  For a given subset $u \subseteq D := \{1,2,\ldots,d\}$ consider the projections $P_u : L^2[0,1]^d \to L^2[0,1]^{|u|}$ given by
$$
P_u f(x_u) = \int_{[0,1]^{d - |u|}} f(x) \, dx^{|u^c|},
$$
were $x_u = \{(x_{i_s})_{s=1}^{|u|} : i_s \in u\}$.  The ANOVA decomposition of $f$ is given by
$$
f(x) = \sum_{u \subseteq D} f_u(x_u)
$$
where each $f_u$ is constructed recursively as
$$
f_u(x_u) := P_u f(x_u) - \sum_{v \subsetneq u} f_v(x_v).
$$
This decomposition is orthogonal in the $L^2[0,1]^d$ inner product; that is,
$$
(f_u, f_g)_{L^2} = 0, \qquad u \neq v.
$$
**I'm trying to get a geometric intuition behind this decomposition, and would appreciate some insights.**  As an example let $d = 2$, so the ANOVA decomposition is given by
$$
f(x_1, x_2) = f_{\emptyset} + f_{\{1\}}(x_1) + f_{\{2\}}(x_2) + f_{\{1,2\}}(x_1, x_2),
$$
where
\begin{align*}
f_\emptyset & = \int_{[0,1]^2} f(x_1,x_2) \, dx_1 dx_2, \\
f_{\{1\}}(x_1) & = \int_{[0,1]} f(x_1,x_2) \, dx_2 - f_\emptyset, \\
f_{\{2\}}(x_2) & = \int_{[0,1]} f(x_1,x_2) \, dx_1 - f_\emptyset, \\
f_{\{1,2\}}(x_2) & = f(x_1,x_2) - f_{\{1\}}(x_1) - f_{\{2\}}(x_2) - f_\emptyset.
\end{align*}
The trouble I'm having is visualizing the orthogonality.  It seems that since $f$ is a function of two variables, I should be able to project it onto its two coordinates, but the $f_{\{1,2\}}$ term is telling me there's another dimension.

Comment: I think this kind of questions are better suited for Math.SE

Comment: the orthogonality is by construction of the $f_u$ : each one is chosen to be orthogonal to the preceding (you should look at [the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process), this is exactly that). and you forgot to say that each $f_u$ is also chosen to minimize the residual $\|f - \sum_{v=1}^u f_u\|^2$

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is easy to visualize if you can visualize the four-dimensional space :). First, imagine two mutually orthogonal planes $l_0,l_1$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and denote $l_\emptyset:=l_0\cap l_1$. Clearly, each vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^3$ has a unique representation
$$
v=v_0+v_1+v_\emptyset
$$ such that $v_{0,1,\emptyset}\in l_{0,1,\emptyset}$ are mutually orthogonal.

Now, suppose the same takes place in $\mathbb{R}^4$. Then, in fact, every vector of the above form would lie in a 3D subspace spanned by $v_0$ and $v_1$, so the best you can achieve is the representation
$$
v=v_{\{0,1\}}+v_0+v_1+v_\emptyset,
$$
where $v_{\{0,1\}}$ is orthogonal to that subspace.

In your actual case, the relevant spaces are spaces of functions that depend on a subset of coordinates only. These are closed infinite-dimensional subspaces, mutually orthogonal (modulo their intersection), and such that $l_{u_1}\oplus l_{u_2}$ has infinite codimension in $l_{u_1\cup u_2}$.